# Property.GetValue - Test for null breaks with inner exception of null reference?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, reflection

I need to scan a bunch of Outlook '.msg' files and am using the MsgReader library to do so. [(MsgReader Library Project on Github)](https://github.com/Sicos1977/MSGReader)
I have written the following method which opens the message, reads through each of the properties and extracts any of those that are marked as 'string' to be added to a dictionary for returning to the caller.
Here's the code:

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetMsgFileDetails(string filepath)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> filedetails = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //try
        {
            string fullpath = Path.Combine(SelectedFolder, filepath);
            var msg = new Storage.Message(fullpath);
            foreach (var prop in msg.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                string pname = prop.Name;

                if (prop.GetValue(msg) != null)
                {
                    object pvalue = prop.GetValue(msg);
                }
                // We only want the strings
                if (prop.GetValue(msg) != null && (prop.GetValue(msg) is string))
                {
                    filedetails.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(msg).ToString());
                }

            }
            return filedetails;
        }
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error trying to load file");
        //    return null;
        //}
    }

 (the try-catch block is commented out to allow easier debugging).
```

It all seems to be working just fine but it hits one of the values which causes the

```
   (prop.GetValue(msg) != null)
```

line to break with a System Reflection TargetInvocationException . The exception details are as follows:

---

```
C:\Users\Brett\source\repos\FileMunger\FileMunger\ViewModels\FolderContext.cs:line 208
at FileThing.ViewModels.FolderContext.GetProperties(String filepath, Boolean showwindow) in C:\Users\Brett\source\repos\FileMunger\FileMunger\ViewModels\FolderContext.cs:line 159
at FileMunger.MainWindow.FileList_Selected(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Brett\source\repos\FileMunger\FileMunger\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 121
at system.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(List`1 unselectedInfos, List`1 selectedInfos)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(ItemInfo info, Boolean assumeInItemsCollection)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.MakeSingleSelection(ListBoxItem listItem)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.NotifyListItemClicked(ListBoxItem item, MouseButton mouseButton)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.HandleMouseButtonDown(MouseButton mouseButton)
at System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
at FileMunger.App.Main()

Inner Exception 1:
 NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

---

This seems to be due to the value of the prop.GetValue evaluating to null, but that is what I am trying to test for.
I realise this might be getting into the depths of reflection where I am not an expert so if anyone has any ideas how to do this check I'd really appreciate it.
Cheers.

Comment: You should try to get to the stack trace of the InnerException. It may well be a bug within MsgReader. You should be able to test that by logging which property it's fetching before it does so, and then you can write the same code without reflection to see what happens.

Comment: If you only want string properties, then don't call `GetValue` until you know property is string. You can check with `prop.PropertyType == typeof(string)`.

Comment: Good idea Daisy, thank you.. I do know which property it is that barfs so I'll try it without reflection as you suggest.
Thanks Evk, but as it happens, the property type that is failing is a string anyway. It is the MailingListHelp property.

Comment: I added a line before the foreach statement basically: 
var msgmailhelp = msg.MailinglistHelp.
it is of type string and is meant to return a null value if nothing present. Instead, it breaks with a System.NullReferenceException. So I guess my next stop is the GitHub Issues section... Thanks again Daisy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am marking this as an answer in case anyone else comes across the same issue. There is indeed a bug in the MsgReader Library. I have raised the issue there and there are a couple of workarounds that have been very kindly provided. The team are also going to fix it so this will hopefully only be short lived. [You can see the Github thread here](https://github.com/Sicos1977/MSGReader/issues/103#issuecomment-388383214)